# Internal links broken when exporting from org mode to markdown and odt

Tags: emacs, markdown, org-mode, odt

### Edit : source example shortened and outputs provided

When exporting from `org-mode`, the internal links are okay for `latex` or
`html` export but are broken for `markdown` (and `odt` as well but that's not my main purpose).

For instance, the following `.org` file:

```
* One section
See the [[another][another]] section.
* Another section<<another>>
```

leads to the following (excerpt):

1. (okay) `.tex` file (see `\label{orgtarget1}` and
   `\hyperref[orgtarget1]{another}`):

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article}
   [...]
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   [...]
   \begin{document}
   [...]
   \section{One section}
   \label{sec:orgheadline1}

   See the \hyperref[orgtarget1]{another} section.

   \section{Another section\label{orgtarget1}}
   \label{sec:orgheadline2}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. (okay) `.html` file (see `<a id="orgtarget1"></a>` and
   `<a href="#orgtarget1">another</a>`):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
   [...]
   <body>
   [...]
   <div id="outline-container-orgheadline1" class="outline-2">
   <h2 id="orgheadline1"><span class="section-number-2">1</span> One section</h2>
   <div class="outline-text-2" id="text-1">
   <p>
   See the <a href="#orgtarget1">another</a> section.
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div id="outline-container-orgheadline2" class="outline-2">
   <h2 id="orgheadline2"><span class="section-number-2">2</span> Another section<a id="orgtarget1"></a></h2>
   </div>
   [...]
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. (**not** okay) `.md` file (see `<a id="orgtarget1"></a>` **but the lack** of
   any `<a href="#orgtarget1">another</a>`):

   ```
   [...]
   # One section<a id="orgheadline1"></a>

   See the another section.

   # Another section<a id="orgtarget1"></a><a id="orgheadline2"></a>
   ```
4. (**not** okay) `.odt` file (see `<a id="orgtarget1"></a>` **but the double**
   `<text:bookmark-start text:name="OrgXref.orgtarget1"/>`: one at the TOC
   level and one at the section level): when clicking on the
   "another" link, we jump *not* at the second section but at its
   corresponding entry in the TOC:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!-- See etc/org/README for copyright information -->
   [...]
   <office:body>
   <office:text>
   [...]

   <text:p text:style-name="Contents_20_1"><text:a xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="#orgheadline1">1. One section</text:a></text:p>

   <text:p text:style-name="Contents_20_1"><text:a xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="#orgheadline2">2. Another section
   <text:bookmark-start text:name="OrgXref.orgtarget1"/>
   <text:bookmark text:name="orgtarget1"/>
   <text:bookmark-end text:name="OrgXref.orgtarget1"/></text:a></text:p>
   [...]
   <text:h text:style-name="Heading_20_1" text:outline-level="1" text:is-list-header="false">
   <text:bookmark-start text:name="OrgXref.orgheadline1"/>
   <text:bookmark text:name="orgheadline1"/>One section
   <text:bookmark-end text:name="OrgXref.orgheadline1"/></text:h>
   <text:p text:style-name="Text_20_body">See the <text:a xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="#orgtarget1">another</text:a> section.
   </text:p>


   <text:h text:style-name="Heading_20_1" text:outline-level="1" text:is-list-header="false">
   <text:bookmark-start text:name="OrgXref.orgheadline2"/>
   <text:bookmark text:name="orgheadline2"/>Another section
   <text:bookmark-start text:name="OrgXref.orgtarget1"/>
   <text:bookmark text:name="orgtarget1"/>
   <text:bookmark-end text:name="OrgXref.orgtarget1"/>
   <text:bookmark-end text:name="OrgXref.orgheadline2"/></text:h>
   </office:text>
   </office:body>
   </office:document-content>
   ```

I know there is a `markdown` mode in `emacs` but I prefer my source to be in
`org-mode` as the resulting `markdown` file does have a table of contents.

Is it a known bug or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: You could cut out 90 – 95% of that text and still have a [good example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You're perfectly right. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Trouble with `.md` export was a bug and is now fixed (since `Org-mode version 8.3.1, elpa org-20150914`).